# How can I use bootstrap to style my custom joomla component

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, components

I am trying to style my custom joomla component but found out using standard bootstrap syntax is not working.

I tried the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the columns are stacked under eachother. I tried adding the bootstrap CDN in my component page, but the Joomla menu falls apart when doing that.

What can I do to make bootstrap work?

Comment: Do you call bootstrap.css in your page ?

Comment: @RémyTesta Yes I included the CDN but this breaks the standard joomla markup

Comment: Can you provide your code or explain where did you put the cdn link. Maybe your joomla theme already using bootstrap. Try to guess which version. Do your website is online ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Joomla 3.x templates and many third party Joomla templates use Bootstrap 2 so Bootstrap 3 or 4 column classes won't necessarily work.

You have a few options:

- Use column classes from the version of Bootstrap that is being loaded on your Joomla website
- Replace the version of Bootstrap that is being loaded with Bootstrap 4 using a third party extension e.g. [Toggle Bootstrap](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/toogle-boostrap) (free) or [jQuery Easy](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy) (free) or similar
- Manually code a solution to replace the version of Bootstrap that is being loaded with Bootstrap 4 (for some example code for this, see the answers to https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/4953/120)
- Change to a Bootstrap 4 template such as JoomShaper Helix Ultimate (free)

I recommend the last option at this will put you in good shape for the upgrade to Joomla 4 within the next 12 months or so. Joomla 4 will use Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Thank you, I agree the last option is probably the best one.

Answer (score 0):

col-md-x will only activate on medium screen sizes (768px) or higher since bootstrap is a mobile first approach. Try changing col-md-4 and col-md-8 to col-4 and col-8

Comment: Does not work, if I recall Bootstrap works with md on all screens if that is your only classname.

Comment: No that is not how it works. Keep your original code and make the window larger, you will see that they will snap into the position you want after 768px. If you wish for it do snap into position after 0px then use col-4 and col-8.